# Merge sort O(n log n) number of operations per level

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This is a question that I have avoided for a long time, but I have a problem understanding why merge sort is O(n * log n), even after reading other answers. Probably it's something dumb I'm overlooking.

What I do understand is that log n comes from the height of the binary tree.
What I do not understand is why the height every level in the tree requires n operations.
Or maybe I'm looking at this entirely the wrong way (?).

Let's say that I have a situation where n = 8:

```
[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 8, 1, 9]
```

... Then I build the binary tree, splitting up each level:

Eventually I will end up with (conveniently sorted):

```
[1, 5], [2, 3], [4, 8], [1, 9]
```

I don't see how merging these will result in 8 operations on the first level (as I understand it, n * log(n) is the number of levels *  the number of operations per level.
Merge of the first two pairs:

I end up with 3 operations, i.e. check 2 against 1 and 5.
Since you know 3 > 2, you don't need to check 1 from the first pair anymore.
I can't find a situation where you need 4 operations per 2 pairs in any worst case.
So how do you end up with 8 operations per level?

I'm not mathematically gifted, I'm still studying currently.
So apologies if I'm looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: Reverse every pair in your list and you have `n` merges on the `i`-th level of the binary tree. Even if you don't merge, you'll probably need to dump the rest of the list into the result for that level, depending on implementation. It's a matter of asymptoticicity (is that a word?) -- what sort of complexity shape a plot of the number of operations in the algorithm looks like.

Comment: Usually you only count the number of comparisions for sorting algorithms.

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry but I still don't get it. Even if you reverse them, the merging activity itself would imply that the 2 pairs are already sorted (by the previous step where every single item is sorted into pairs). So I don't see how the merging of 2 pairs ever requires more than 3 operations (?).

Comment: OK, but there are `n / 2` pairs, so that'd be `n` just for the second-to-last level you're showing, no? I'd forget about merge sort and focus on convincing yourself that merging two lists is `O(n)`.

Comment: @ggolen This is where I'm sort of stuck... there are 4 pairs, and in the binary tree, they are merged per 2 pairs. So I end up with 6 instead of 8 (=n) operations on this level. Unless I'm totally mistaken in my way of thinking. Edit: about that convincing myself, that's what I'm trying to do...

Comment: In big-O notation, `O(n)` and `O(n/2)` are the same. `n` doesn't mean the exact number of inputs, it just means "some amount directly proportional to the number of inputs".

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That explains a lot, wasn't so obvious thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the last step where you merge two lists into one. If the lists share the same length n/2 you need at most n-1 comparisions looking for the smallest element in front of one list given that they shrink at the same speed. Otherwise, you may end up with less operations. Similary on other layers you get below n operations, the number should even be slightly decreasing. But O(n log n) is an upper bound and further inspection would show that merge sort is not asymptotically better.

Further inspection:
Let n=2^k. We have k layers. One layer with at most n-1 ops, one with two times n/2 - 1 ops ... until n/2 times 1 op.
We should get n-1 + 2(n/2 - 1) +4(n/4-1)... + n/2(1)= n-1 + n - 2 + n - 4 +... + n - n/2 = kn - (1+2+4+...+2^(k-1)) = kn - (2^k - 1) = n log n - n +1.

n log n grows faster than n and 1, so we even get θ(n log n) as we are only interested in the fastest growing Part.